# How do I use canon p-208ii scanner on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, scanner, canon

`lsusb` shows me

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1083:1660 Canon Electronics, Inc. CANON   P-208II
```

but Document Scanner can't find it

Answer (score -1):

There is a switch on the back for Auto Start, set it to Off for Linux, On is for Windows.